# Number of UDP padding-bytes

Tags: udp, padding

I am currently looking at the structure of UDP-packets in a DHCP-setup-scenario and have troubles figuring out the number of padding-bytes that I need at the end of the UDP-packet.

I traced the data using Wireshark and can understand the content of the Ethernet-frame down to the UDP-level. What I fail to understand is how many padding bytes 0x00 are added to the UDP-data.
In my scenario I have a UDP-length of 0x0134 (=308 Bytes/Octets, given from Wireshark), the last seven octets are just padding (=0x00).
The Wikipedia-article for UDP (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol), paragraph "Checksum Computation" mentions padding with Zero-Octets to make multiple of Two Octets. 
I initially interpreted this as having multiple of two as my UDP-length. However if that was true then I would not need 7 padding octets but could live with one single padding-octet:
Here's an equivalent of the end of the trace:

Byte-#....Content
...
299d.......0xF9
300d.......0x2B
301d.......0xFF
302d.......0x00
=> Here I would already have a multiple of 2, however I still get six more padding-bytes.

Can somebody help me understand where these six are coming from?

Cheers,

ye_ol_man